# Not working on jquery 1.9.1 version

Tags: jquery

```
$('#postform').submit(function() {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
            return false;
});
```

The code above is not working when i upgraded my site to jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function ajaxSubmit is not a core function of the jQuery library but a plugin called "form".

You can download in here: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

After including the corresponding js file into your page, your code should work.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have included jquery form plugin but when i changed the version of jquery from 1.2.6 to 1.9.1 the above code stopped working.

Comment: Are you sure that you have included the latest version of the plugin? Because the one from that page is for jQuery version 1.5 and later. Maybe you are still using an old version of the plugin which worked with the jQuery version you updated from.

Comment: Thank you @Rob I have updated the plugin now i had a new issue with ajaxsubmit the ajax call is not returning data on success

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery ajax to submit your form insted of `ajaxSubmit()`

syntax.

```
var frm = $('#postform');

       $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {

                //call back handling here

                }

        });
```

refrence : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/